# How to insert/update values into custom fields of grid using upload button

Tags: acumatica

In Physical Inventory Review screen, i added some custom fields to grid, am using excel file to import data. My question is how can i insert/update values into my custom fields. I selected mapping correctly but could not able to insert/update values. Can someone please help me.

Comment: are the custom fields enabled (not enabled=false)? are you using the Acumatica import button to select the file and import from or is this some custom process you wrote?

Comment: Hi Brendan, the custom fields are enabled, am also able to update some text manually from screen. Am using Acumatica standard "Load Records from File" button. Just created fields to save value no additional customization are made.

Answer (score 0):

Inside INPIReview graph appears that there is a method that handle the import: PrepareImportRow

- :( Is not virtual so you can not override it
- :) I found a trick that may help

Use PXImportAttribute event to gain control of the imported object

```
public class INPIReviewExt : PXGraphExtension<INPIReview>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        PXImportAttribute piDetails = this.Base.PIDetail.Attributes.Find(a => a is PXImportAttribute) as PXImportAttribute;
        piDetails.RowImporting += PiDetailsRowImporting;
    }

    private void PiDetailsRowImporting(object sender, PXImportAttribute.RowImportingEventArgs e)
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

**Attention**:

- the event is invoked before PrepareImportRow. You must insert the new record with all keys in the cache.
- Also became a little complicated the fact that Acumatica use INBarCodeItem object instead INPIDetail. With a little attention you may succeed.
- If you generate the event method with TAB on V.S. you will get an underscore ("*") char on the method name. Acumatica will throw an event subscriber event error. Just remove the "*" from the name of the method (like I did)